# QSqlRelationTableModel->setData не отправляет int-ы

Tags: qt

```
void MainWindow::on_addButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlRelationalTableModel * model = db->getModel();
    int rowCount = model->rowCount();
    model->insertRow(rowCount);
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("add_date")),QVariant(ui->dateAdd->dateTime()));
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("district")),QVariant(ui->district->currentIndex()+1));
    if(!model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("cert_id")),QVariant(ui->idNumber->text().toInt()),Qt::EditRole)) {
        qDebug() « model->lastError().databaseText(); // не записывается, QSqlError(-1, "", "")
    }
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("name")),QVariant(ui->name->text()));
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("birth_date")),QVariant(ui->birthDate->dateTime()));
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("address")),QVariant(ui->address->text()));
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("phone")),QVariant(ui->phoneNumber->text()));
    model->setData(model->index(rowCount, model->fieldIndex("vtekNumber")),ui->vtekNumber->text().toInt()); // не записывается
    if(!model->submitAll()) {
        qDebug() « model->lastError().driverText(); // 
    }
    qDebug() « model->lastError(); // QSqlError(-1, "", "")
}
```

Не добавляются два поля в таблицу (sqlite), вместо них - NULL. Оба - int, оба берутся из QLineEdit.

Comment: а ui->idNumber->text().toInt() точно инт возвращает? Вообще, насколько я помню, sqlite в принципе по барабану инт или не инт туда писать, он один фиг не проверяет типы и кажется хранит все текстом

Comment: Да, всё нормально возвращает. И в QVariant оборачивал, всё равно не помогает.